# Linux read external disk data, cannot mount

Tags: linux, mount, disk

I just received a hard disk from other people and it includes some data. I want to read the data inside this disk. However, when I try to mount it, it shows:

```
~ lsblk

NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 

├─sda1   8:1    0   217G  0 part /

├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 

└─sda5   8:5    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]

sdc      8:32   0  74.6G  0 disk 

sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

~ sudo mount /dev/sdc /media/new

mount: /dev/sdc: can't read superblock

~ udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdc

Object /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/block_devices/sdc is not a mountable filesystem.
```

So what can I do to read the data inside this disk? I am not sure whether I can use command like mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdc, which seems will initialize the disk and erase the data.

Comment: It is more a superuser question, not a stackoverflow one. Anyway... if somebody give you the disk, he can tell what is the format used to write it. If it was part of a RAID stack / encoded at hardware level then sorry but you are skrewed

Comment: ok, thanks. I would contact the disk owner about this

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The I/O error you get is a very bad sign. If this is a SSD it is probably completely dead. If it is a hard drive you will need to use specialized recovery tools that may be able to read parts of it, depending on how it was damaged. Tools like the old DOS based SpinRIte or dd_rescue in Linux, or other proprietary forensics tools. Past that you'd need data recovery services that could take the drive apart and read the platters using specialized hardware tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use gparted to get some infos ?

Comment: yes. It shows the disk is unallocated. But when I start gparted, it shows Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc

Comment: That sound like your disc is doomed. As mentioned above, try to use ddrescue which acts like dd but with more capabilities.